# c# loop through linq results and update field

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following in linq:

```
var rss = result.Select(x => new { x.SampleDate, x.DataValue })
                .OrderBy(a => a.SampleDate).ToList();
```

Note that `SampleDate` is a nullable field.

For what I need it more extensive but I like to look through `rss` and add milliseconds to the `SampleDate` with a foreach.

I tried:

```
 foreach (var r in rss)
 {
     r.SampleDate = r.SampleDate.Value.AddMilliseconds(1);              
 }
```

but get message:

> SamplePoint cannot be assigned, it is read-only.

There is a `{ get; set; }` on it. Is there a problem on how I am assigning?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because `rss` is a list of an anonymous type and not of the type of the items in your `result` collection. These anonymous types are immutable and that is why you can't assign the values.

Instead try this:

```
var rss = result.Select(x => new { SampleDate = x.SampleDate?.AddMilliseconds(1), x.DataValue })
                .OrderBy(a => a.SampleDate).ToList();
```

Notice the use of the Null-conditional operator [introduced in C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.Anyway to do this in foreach loop as I need to do some extensive processing.

Comment: @NatePet - project to a custom type and not an anonymous object

Comment: @NatePet Why does having "extensive processing" mean you need a foreach loop?  Just do it in the select.

Comment: @NatePet - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a concrete type to do this as anonymous types (`new { ... }`) cannot be modified once created.

```
public class RssData
{
    public DateTime? SampleDate {get; set;}
    public string DataValue {get; set;} // use string only if appropriate - I guessed at its type
}
```

Then, in whatever method you're doing what you're doing...

```
public void YourMethod()
{
    var rss = result.Select(x => new RssData { x.SampleDate, x.DataValue })
              .OrderBy(a => a.SampleDate).ToList(); // .ToList() may be redundant here as the foreach below will force the iteration, but that's not really the point of this. :)

    foreach(var r in rss)
    {
        if(r.SampleDate.HasValue)
            r.SampleDate = r.SampleDate.Value.AddMilliseconds(1);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...